# SQLServer - Multiple PIVOT on same column

Tags: sql-server, query, pivot

I have a table data like the below with **Type Regular/Irregular** from January to December.

I need a query to do this data like the below table: January with below divided into two-jRegular & jIrregular. whole the year data using the PIVOT or Cross tab.

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Details](   
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
        [Type] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,     
        [Header] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,   
        [SubHeader] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,    
        [January] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,    
        [February] [decimal](18, 0) NOT NULL,   
        [March] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,  
        [April] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,  
        [May] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,    
        [June] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,   
        [July] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL ) ON [PRIMARY]
        
        GO SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Details] ON 
        
        GO INSERT [dbo].[Details] ([ID], [Type], [Header], [SubHeader], 
    [January], [February], [March], [April], [May], [June], [July]) 
    VALUES (2, N'Regular', N'Item-1', N'A.Sub-Item1', 
            CAST(64.92 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(57 AS Decimal(18, 0)), 
            CAST(89.67 AS Decimal(18, 2)), 
    CAST(99.20 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(76.34 AS Decimal(18, 2)), 
    CAST(23.33 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(32.23 AS Decimal(18, 2))) 
    GO 
    
    INSERT [dbo].[Details] ([ID], [Type], [Header], [SubHeader], 
    [January], [February], [March], [April], [May], [June], [July]) 
    VALUES (3, N'Irregular', N'Item-1', N'A.Sub-Item1', 
   CAST(43.45 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(65 AS Decimal(18, 0)), 
   CAST(65.88 AS Decimal(18, 2)), 
    CAST(56.77 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(45.65 AS Decimal(18, 2)), 
    CAST(56.87 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(67.55 AS Decimal(18, 2))) 
    GO 
    
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Details] OFF 
    GO

    SELECT Header, SubHeader,
      Regular, Irregular,
      FRegular, FIrregular,
      MrRegular, MrIrregular
      FROM (SELECT Header, SubHeader, Type, 
           'F'+Type AS FType, 
           'Mr'+Type as MType, 
           'Ap'+Type AType, 
           'Ma'+Type as May,
      [January], [February], [March] 
      from [CashFlow].[dbo].[Details] ) p
    
      PIVOT (MAX(January) FOR Type in (Regular, Irregular)) AS JPVT
      PIVOT (MAX([February]) FOR FType in (FRegular, FIrregular)) AS FPVT
      PIVOT (MAX(March) FOR MType in (MrRegular, MrIrregular)) AS MrPVT
```

[image]

Any one can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Group by Header and Subheader and take the sum like below

```
SELECT Header, SubHeader,
  Sum(Regular), Sum(Irregular),
  Sum(FRegular), Sum(FIrregular),
  Sum(MrRegular), Sum(MrIrregular)
  FROM (SELECT Header, 
               SubHeader, 
               Type, 'F'+Type AS FType, 
               'Mr'+Type as MType, 
               'Ap'+Type AType, 
               'Ma'+Type as May,
               January], [February], [March] 
  from [CashFlow].[dbo].[Details] ) p

  PIVOT (MAX(January) FOR Type in (Regular, Irregular)) AS JPVT
  PIVOT (MAX([February]) FOR FType in (FRegular, FIrregular)) AS FPVT
  PIVOT (MAX(March) FOR MType in (MrRegular, MrIrregular)) AS MrPVT
Group by Header, SubHeader
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way that you can do it is to unpivot your data first, then pivot it in a single operation.  See the example below.  The only change I had to make was that the column for February wasn't the same as the others (decimal(18,0) rather than decimal(18,2)) but after fixing that, it worked great.

```
;WITH CTE_UP AS
    (
    SELECT [Header] 
        , [SubHeader]
        , [MonthType] = LEFT([Month], 3) + [Type]
        , [Value] 
    FROM [CashFlow].[dbo].[Details]
        UNPIVOT ([Value] FOR [Month] IN (January, February, March, April, May, June, July)) AS unpvt 
    )
, CTE_P AS
    (
    SELECT [Header]
        , [SubHeader]
        , JanRegular AS Regular
        , JanIrregular AS Irregular
        , FebRegular AS FRegular
        , FebIrregular AS FIrregular
        , MarRegular AS MrRegular
        , MarIrregular AS MrIrregular
    FROM CTE_UP AS UP 
        PIVOT (SUM([Value]) FOR MonthType IN (JanRegular, JanIrregular, FebRegular, FebIrregular, MarRegular, MarIrregular)) AS pvt
    )
SELECT * FROM CTE_P
```